# Durda de Registros (Insert )en C# SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estimados: Junto con Saludar y esperando que se encuentren bien.
Paso a dejar una duda la cual me tiene con intriga.
Resulta que estoy realizando un proyecto (Sistema de inventario para Bodega)en C# con SQLite
-. El cual no guarda los datos en la BD   pero si me lista estos datos en el software. Es decir realizo un insert directo a la BD y estos registros me los lista y guarda n la BD

Por otro lado, cuando ingreso datos en el software, no me los guarda en la BD  pero igual me los lista como producto ingresado, ingreso a la BD y no aparecen.

he revisado las Querys y procedimientos y segun mis ojos estan bien (Obiamente no lo estan xq no pasaria esto).

PDT: estoy recien con C# y Sql Lite

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo el código que tienes para reproducir tu escenario, considera estas recomendaciones sobre cómo formular preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y además, sigue https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo nada... Sera que tenes dos bases, y vos miras una, y el programa usa otra??? porque no hay datos que aparezcan magicamente, y no hay datos que desaparezcan magicamente. Igual asi como esta planteada la pregunta, no podemos hacer mucho, porque solo describis un problema, pero las causas pueden ser miles...

Comment: ¿No será que la BD que usa el programa de C# es otra, sea porque la has embebido en el programa o por lo que sea? Da la impresión que por un lado tienes una BD y por otro otra. No te puedo decir más, porque no programo en C#, es *lógica* simplemente.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas confundiendo los datos, puede ser que estes guardando los datos solamente en la ram y es por eso que te los lista, pero no los estas guardando en la BD, si al cerrar y abrir el sofware los datos se borran es por lo que te comento, pero es preferible que pongas todo el codigo para ver lo que esta pasando realmente.

Comment: Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, espera a que tengas la reputación necesaria para poder comentar, date una vuelta en [answer].